# Abbreviate column names during data frame print

Tags: r, mobile, printing

R's abbreviate() is useful for truncating, among other things, the column names of a data frame to a set length, with nice checks to ensure uniqueness, etc.:

```
abbreviate(names(dframe), minlength=2)
```

One could, of course, use this function to abbreviate the column names in-place and then print out the altered data frame

```
>>names(dframe) <- abbreviate(names(dframe), minlength=2)
>>dframe
```

But I would like to print out the data frame with abbreviated column names *without* altering the data frame in the process. Hopefully this can be done through a simple format option in the print() call, though my search through the help pages of print and format methods like print.data.frame didn't turn up any obvious solution (the available options seem more for formatting the column values, not their names).

So, does print() or format() have any options that call abbreviate() on the column names? If not, is there a way to apply abbreviate() to the column names of a data frame before passing it to print(), again without altering the passed data frame?

The more I think about it, the more I think that the only way would be to pass print() a copy of the data frame with already abbreviated column names. But this is not a solution for me, because I don't want to constantly be updating this copy as I update the original during an interactive session. The original column names must remain unaltered, because I use  which(colnames(dframe)=="name_of_column") to interface with the data.

My ultimate goal is to work better remotely on the small screen of my mobile device when working in ssh apps like Server Auditor. If the the column names are abbreviated to only 2-3 characters I can still recognize them but can fit much more data on the screen. Perhaps there even are R packages that are better suited for condensed printing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your own print method

```
print.myDF <- function(x, abbr = TRUE, minlength = 2, ...) {
    if (abbr) {
        names(x) <- abbreviate(names(x), minlength = minlength) 
    }
    print.data.frame(x, ...)
}
```

Then add the class `myDF` to the data and print

```
class(iris) <- c("myDF", class(iris))
head(iris, 3)
#   S.L S.W P.L P.W     Sp
# 1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
print(head(iris, 3), abbr = FALSE)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
print(head(iris, 3), minlength = 5)
#   Spl.L Spl.W Ptl.L Ptl.W  Specs
# 1   5.1   3.5   1.4   0.2 setosa
# 2   4.9   3.0   1.4   0.2 setosa
# 3   4.7   3.2   1.3   0.2 setosa
```

Comment: Right,  just steal BondedDust's answer :-)  OK, srsly, nice work with the addition of a `class` and default argument for `abbr` .

Comment: Shoot! Duh functions already work with copies, so that takes care of not altering the original. I, too, find defining a `class` to be a very clean solution. That will def become part of this noob's future programming practice :)

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite `print.data.frame`:

```
 print.data.frame <-
               function(x) setNames( print(x), 
                                abbreviate(names(dframe), minlength=2) )
```

(You will probably want an auxiliary printfull.data.frame to which you first copy print.data.frame.)

Comment: Reading this after 8 years. A requirement to get a `clean_names()` equivalent exists e.g. `abbr.names()` and that should work in a magrittr pipe